# Typescript - toString() doesn't change the property type

Tags: reactjs, string, typescript, state, tostring

I get the following error in the `valorControlo` property:

```
Property 'valorControlo' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Then I insert the `toString()` but it doesn't help at all. Here's the code:

```
const [isBarExtended, setIsBarExtended] = useState(false);
const [sidenavObj, setSidenavObj] = useState('');
const stringToBool = (v: string) => Boolean(v !== undefined && v != null && v != '' && v.toUpperCase() === 'TRUE');

useEffect(() => {
    if (!isDefined(sidenavObj)) {
      ...
    } 
    else {
      setIsBarExtended(stringToBool(sidenavObj.valorControlo.toString()))
    }
  }, [sidenavObj]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`valorControlo` is never declared or used in the code you posted, `sidenavObj` is just a string, it doesn't have the `valorControlo` property.

Try: `setIsBarExtended(stringToBool(sidenavObj))`